# XUnit Service Layer Testing Core 3 System.ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, xunit.net

Although I have experience with TDD in another language, I am having a difficult time understanding testing in .NET Core 3. I am using Entity Framework, and trying to produce tests on my service layer. I have seen a few examples with repositories and some based on API, but I haven't figured out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm getting a `System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')` error when running the test.

ICustomerService.cs

```cs
public interface ICustomerService
{
    List<Customer> GetCustomers();
}
```

CustomerService.cs

```cs
public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{
    private readonly DbContext _db;
    public CustomerService(DbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public List<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        return _db.Customer.ToList();
    }
}
```

CustomerServiceTests.cs

```cs
[Fact]
public void GetCustomersReturnsRecords()
  {
    // Arrange
    var cntxt = new Mock<DbContext>();
    CustomerService cs = new CustomerService(cntxt.Object);

    // Act
    var result = cs.GetCustomers();

    //Asserts here
    Assert.NotNull(result);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to mock the `DbContext`, consider using an in-memory database.

> Unit testing
>
> Consider testing a piece of business logic that might
> need to use some data from a database, but is not inherently testing
> the database interactions. One option is to use a test double such as
> a mock or fake.
>
> We use test doubles for internal testing of EF Core. However, we never
> try to mock DbContext or IQueryable. Doing so is difficult,
> cumbersome, and fragile. Don't do it.
>
> Instead we use the EF in-memory database when unit testing something
> that uses DbContext. In this case using the EF in-memory database is
> appropriate because the test is not dependent on database behavior.
> Just don't do this to test actual database queries or updates.

Reference [Testing code that uses EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/#unit-testing)

That is the suggest approach from documentation.

```
[Fact]
public void GetCustomersReturnsRecords() {
    // Arrange
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
    builder.UseInMemoryDatabase();
    var options = builder.Options;
    using(var context = new MyDbContext(options)) {
        CustomerService subject = new CustomerService(context);

        // Act
        var result = subject.GetCustomers();

        //Asserts here
        Assert.NotNull(result);
    }
}
```

Reference [Testing with the EF In-Memory Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory)

Comment: Thanks for getting me on the right track. The lack of documentation and the new full version Core releases are making it hard to keep up.